# How are frames dropped in 59.94 fps drop-frame timecode?

Tags: timecode, smpte

The pattern for dropping frames in 29.97 drop-frame SMPTE timecode is well documented (2 frames at every minute except when minute is a multiple of 10).

I was wondering how it works with 59.94 fps drop-frame timecode? I guess it needs to be twice the amount of frames dropped, but what is the exact pattern?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a question about video.

Comment: This would be a good fit for [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) however it is unfortunately too old for me to migrate it.

Comment: I reasked it there, question may be closed here. Thanks for keeping it clean.